# Should I change ownership of files in /usr/local/share/locale?

Tags: macos, permissions, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew, and `brew doctor` returns a lot of warnings, one of which is this:

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/locale aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

[list of directories in /usr/local/share/locale]
```

`/usr/local/share/locale` contains directories which have mostly two-letter names (language name abbreviations?), each of which has a `LC_MESSAGES` directory that contains a `gnupg.mo` file.

Shouldn't things like localized strings be owned by root and not writable to normal users?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm going to set the group ownership to `admin` and do `chmod g+w`, which should make them writable for me. I still would like an answer as to what the best thing to do is.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some packages may be managed by an account created for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install these files? If so, then you know what they are for. You can probably delete them if you don't need them anymore.

Whatever, setting locale files to group writable is perfectly safe. A malicious script could in theory change the spanish translation of whatever tool it is that got installed there before Homebrew: not the end of the world.

**Update:** The best thing to do is to figure out whose files they are and then delete them and use `brew` to install whatever it is that you just deleted. Mixing `/usr/local` with brewed and unbrewed stuff is not a good idea unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I don't remember installing anything in a locale directory; it might just have been OS X. And a malicious script would have to be able to authenticate as a user in the admin group first. ;)

Comment: OS X never installs anything in `/usr/local`.

Comment: Must have been gnupg (see my latest edit).