# How do I read numeric permissions greater than 777?

Tags: macos, file-permissions

I noticed this just now, when using `find` and `stat` to get the permissions of all the items in `/usr/local/share/locale` before I [recursively change them](https://superuser.com/questions/460900). `stat` shows the permissions in a numeric format that I'm not familiar with—all the directories are `40755` and the files are `100644`. I'm guessing that the last three are just normal octal permissions (which I already know about), but what do the `40`s and `100`s mean?

Comment: `stat` uses symbolic (`drwx`) output on my system. How are you calling it? `which stat`?

Comment: The full command I used is `find /usr/local/share/locale -exec stat -f '%p %N' {} \;`. `stat` is `/usr/bin/stat`. This is on OS X Mountain Lion; are you on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat(1)` is primarily a wrapper for `stat(2)`, and the man page of `stat(2)` reveals this:

```
 The status information word st_mode has the following bits:

 #define S_IFMT   0170000  /* type of file */
 #define S_IFIFO  0010000  /* named pipe (fifo) */
 #define S_IFCHR  0020000  /* character special */
 #define S_IFDIR  0040000  /* directory */
 #define S_IFBLK  0060000  /* block special */
 #define S_IFREG  0100000  /* regular */
 #define S_IFLNK  0120000  /* symbolic link */
 #define S_IFSOCK 0140000  /* socket */
 #define S_IFWHT  0160000  /* whiteout */
 #define S_ISUID  0004000  /* set user id on execution */
 #define S_ISGID  0002000  /* set group id on execution */
 #define S_ISVTX  0001000  /* save swapped text even after use */
 #define S_IRUSR  0000400  /* read permission, owner */
 #define S_IWUSR  0000200  /* write permission, owner */
 #define S_IXUSR  0000100  /* execute/search permission, owner */
```

So the leading 100 means it's a regular file, and the leading 40 means it's a directory.

Comment: They're all in octal because octal is convenient for the low 9 bits (rwxrwxrwx) and mixing octal with decimal would be a disaster. (S_IFREG would be 32768, which is sort of a recognizable number, but the combination of that with permission bits 0644 would be 33188, which is much harder to read than 0100644)